How to fix a Wordfence scan that doesn't finish?
I've used Wordfence fo my website on Worpress.org (through hostinger) and my scan yesterday showed me this message:
Error writing value for wfsd_engine (MySQLi error: [2006] MySQL server has gone away)
I've run a lot of scans between yesterday and today and it's always the same : the scan can't finish and keep running endlessly at the "malware scan" part. This issue seems to show up only when I run the scan. I didn't notice any changes or difficulties with my website till now.
I've tried to fix it myself looking for solutions online but since I'm not a professionnal it's difficult. It starts happening when I was changing the setting of LiteSpeed cache and Wordfence (following youtube videos). I've tried to change back the original settings of Litespeed cache but the issue is still here.
Can someone please help me ? Thanks for your kindness, Noelie

You can try to update the performance Setting of WordPress and see if it help.
You can change it at Wordfence > Scan > Scan Options and Scheduling
Over here in Performance Setting increase the numbers for following 2 options

How much memory should Wordfence request when scanning
Maximum execution time for each scan stage

Hope this helps

Thanks fo your help. I will try
